# AWS Step Function Cannot read properties of undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, typeerror, aws-step-functions

Currently writing nodejs code that takes input from an event to start a state machine in AWS Step functions. However I keep getting the error:

```
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'number')",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'number')",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:29:35)"
  ]
}
```

when the event is passed through as a state input, but when I use the same event as a test in the actual lambda console of the same function as the one in the state machine, theres no error and I get the response I expect:

```
START RequestId: a4a6cd87-b869-456f-9d7d-72eabe551eda Version: $LATEST
2022-08-11T09:47:50.190Z    a4a6cd87-b869-456f-9d7d-72eabe551eda    INFO    [
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
    '<!DOCTYPE XGResponse SYSTEM >\n' +
    '<XGResponse>\n' +
    `   <Failure code="403">Authentication failed. Unknown authentication code . </Failure>\n` +
    '</XGResponse>'
]
END RequestId: a4a6cd87-b869-456f-9d7d-72eabe551eda
REPORT RequestId: a4a6cd87-b869-456f-9d7d-72eabe551eda  Duration: 698.45 ms Billed Duration: 699 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 94 MB  Init Duration: 543.89 ms
```

is there something changing the event when its passed as a state input vs when its passed as a regular event?

the code that takes event and starts state machine and how the event looks when inputted into state machine before it fails and returns the type-error:

```
 var params = {
        stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states',
        input: JSON.stringify({event})
    };
```

```
"details": {
        "input": "{\"event\":{\"rawData\":{\"number\":[\"TBNISCLUI5\"],\"article_code\":[\"5339985\"]}}}",
        "inputDetails": {
            "truncated": false
        },
        "name": ""
    },
```

the function in the state machine that actually parses event:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

var product = {
    order_number : '',
    article_code: '',
};
var prods = [];
var responses = [];
var data = await event['rawData'];
var numbers = await data['number'];
for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    product[i] = {  
        order_number : [numbers][i],
   };
```

and how the event looks in the function test console:

```
{
  "rawData": {
    "number": [
      "TBNISCLUI5"
    ],
    "article_code": [
      "5339985"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a minute, really don't understand whats happening to the event that the same function can't parse when its via the state machine.

any help is appreciated, thank you